# Implementaiton of Continuous Ranked Probability Score (CRPS) when Observation is a Distribution

Tags: forecasting, scoring-rules

The most general form of the Continuous Ranked Probability Score (CRPS) is defined as,

$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \big( \hat{F}^e(x) - F^0(x)\big)^2dx,$

for some true distribution, $F^0$, and empirical distribution, $F^e$. However most analysis using CRPS focuses on the case where a single observation, $y$, is the truth, $F^0(x) = 1(x\le y)$. When this is the case, CRPS can be broken down into the following form which is easy to compute,

$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \big( \hat{F}^e(x) - 1(x \le y)\big)^2dx = \mathbb{E}_p|X-y| - \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}_P | X - X^{\prime}| \approx \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m |X_i-y| - \frac{1}{2m^2} \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^m |X_i - X_j|,$

where $X$ are random draws from the distribution $P$, and $X_i$ is the $i^{th}$ ordered draw from the distribution $X$. The rightmost term is an approximation using the empirical CDF.

What I am curious to know is if I can implement something similar when instead of a single observation, $y$, as the truth, I have a collection of true observation, $Y$. Would the above formula simply be

$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \big( \hat{F}^e(x) - F^0(x) \big)^2dx = \mathbb{E}_p|X-Y| - \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}_P | X - X^{\prime}| \approx \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m |X_i-Y_i| - \frac{1}{2m^2} \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^m |X_i - X_j|,$

or would there need to be an extra term capturing the squares of $Y$ as well as cross-products of $X$ and $Y$?